# Срабатывание кнопки после нажатия на Enter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, form

Столкнулся с проблемой, есть чат, чат отправляет запросы и обновляет таблицу чата по средством Ajax но почему-то при вводе текста в строку нужно "Курсором" наводить на кнопку отправить что не является удобным для большинства юзеров на моем сайте, как сделать так чтобы кнопка срабатывала после нажатия на клавишу Enter? вот код -

```
div class="mainchat" id="chatik">

    <div id="chatblock">

    </div>
    <?
    if ($_SESSION['USER_LOGIN_IN'] == 1) {
    ?>
        <div class="chatsender">
                <input type="text" class="chattext" id="chatmessange" autocomplete="off" required>
                <input type="submit" id="chatsubmit" class="chatsubmits" value="Отправить">
        </div>
    <?
    } else {
    ?>
        <div class="chatnouser"><span>Только для зарегестрированных пользователей</span></div>
    <?
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

ajax обработчик -

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var button = $("#chatsubmit");
    button.click(function() {
        var text = $("#chatmessange").val();
        if (text == "") {
            alert("Текста нет, ебалай");
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/catr/get",
                type: "POST",
                data: ({
                    text: text
                }),
                success: function() {
                    $("#chatmessange").val("");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    window.setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/catr/show",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#chatblock").html(data);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить слушатель события `keypress` на поле ввода текста сообщения:

```js
$('#chatmessage').on('keypress', function(e){
    if(e.key == 'Enter'){
        $('#chatsubmit').trigger('click');
        // Отмена действия по умолчанию
        return false;
    }
});
```

### EDITED

Comment: noreply если не умеешь в конструктив, немного инфы: 
1. лучше всегда использовать тройное равно, 2. function можно выбросить [подробнее(да и вообще не лишним будет)](https://habr.com/ru/post/305900/#2), 3. про семиколоны не забывай, это важно 4. (субъективно) пробельчики - фу-бе

Comment: @Vadim Ну что же, давай пройдемся по твоим пунктам. 1. В данном случае сравниаем не пустые строки или String с Boolean, поэтому тройное равно только добавляет лишний символ к коду и никакой смысловой нагрузки не несет. 2. ES2016, это, конечно, очень хорошо, я не спорю, но не везде поддерживается, плюс, например, не все программы по обфускации кода поддерживают этот стандарт, а программист должен писать код с гибкостью не только под современные стандарты, но еще с обратной совместимостью. 3. И где же я их забыл? 4. Зато красиво.

Comment: 1. Я имею ввиду, лучше приучиться сразу и везде, чем на полшышечки 2. Стандарт 2015 не везде поддерживается, понялпринялзаписал. 3. Ласт строка, 4. По мне нет, ибо ни читаемости, ни удобности они не добавляют, а только наоборот.

Comment: Спасибо за критику, приму к сведению.

Answer (score 0):

Используй первую комментированную строку, если .yourInput динамически создается

Про евент: [ключ-вныз тут](https://api.jquery.com/keydown/)

```js
// $('body').on('keydown', '.yourInput', (e)=>{
$('.yourInput:first').keydown((e)=>{
    if(e.keyCode === 13 || e.key === 'Enter'){
        e.preventDefault(); // удаляем "обновление" страницы
        $('.yourConfirmButton').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо) не думал что у меня что-то выйдет))